# How to get text of Custom HTML in Joomla

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-module, joomla3.4

I know that we can get text of an article  as:

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart=0){ 
    print_r($article->text);
```

Now is there any way to get text of module that is designed from Custom HTML using editor?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('custom', 'Custom Html');
$module->content;
```

Where the first parameter is the module name (for this question is always gonna be 'custom' ) and the second parameter is the module title ('Custom Html' in this example)

[Api Docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModuleHelper.html)

[image]

## UPDATE

I've forgot to mention, the module requested must be published and set to appear in the current page.
If it's a module that I would access only programmatically, I would publish the module on all pages in a position no used by any template

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure I can call it in my function onContentPrepare?
As it gives me this error:
`Trying to get property of non-object in /home/agarg/public_html/joomla34/plugins/content/modulebox/modulebox.php on line 36`
Also on vardump($module) results in NULL

Comment: @Anant Did you resolve your problem? Did you pass the correct params to `JModuleHelper::getModule`?

Comment: Yes I did it as per your suggestion